# Concat variable value and constant value in a xml file

Tags: spring

I use spring and in a configuration file i try to concat value.

I tried this:

```
<property name="url" value="#{'${jdbc.as400.url}'+ ';libraries=*LIBL'}" />
```

but It don't seem to be the right way.
`libraries=*LIBL` don't seem to be saw

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `+`. This should work:

```
<property name="url" value="${jdbc.as400.url};libraries=*LIBL" />
```